# Can I add a select input type on AWS Amplify sign up form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a react project using AWS amplify, and user cognito pool, I have the authetication setup like this:

```
export default withAuthenticator(App, {
  signUpConfig: {
    signUpFields: [
      {
        label: 'Company', key: 'company', required: true, type: 'string',
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

And this new custom field for Company works very well, but I'd like to add a select input, the docs doesn't helped much on that, so I'd like to know if it's possible, and if yes, how to do that.

[Amplify docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/react#signup-configuration)

Comment: Was wondering about exactly the same adaptation. Have you found a way to do it?

Comment: I didn't find any solution for it. I guess the only one should be a custom form and them calling the sign-in functions by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't much help at the moment and may require a lot of work if you already have the components, routing and nav of your application built out, but I read somewhere (can't remember where) that they're switching to a slot-based component which can be incorporated with state handling functionality which you can find [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/react#sign-up). I'd recommend incorporating this new approach sooner rather than later as it appears Amplify is shifting away from the `withAuthenticator` HOC.

I'm building in TypeScript, but there is a JS implementation which looks almost identical, here's some [examples](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/react#use-cases) of both (*also seen at bottom of post*). Notice the `<AmplifyAuthenticator>` component, where you can customize your sign-in/sign-up components in the exported `App`, which is now adopting the naming convention of `AuthStateApp` such as the following:

```
const AuthStateApp: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [authState, setAuthState] = React.useState<AuthState>();
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState<object | undefined>();

  React.useEffect(() => {
      return onAuthUIStateChange((nextAuthState, authData) => {
          setAuthState(nextAuthState);
          setUser(authData)
      });
  }, []);

  return authState === AuthState.SignedIn && user ? (
      <div className="App">
          <div>Hello, {user.username}</div>
          <AmplifySignOut />
      </div>
  ) : (
    <AmplifyAuthenticator>
    <AmplifySignUp
      slot="sign-up"
      formFields={[
        { type: "email", label: 'Email', placeholder: 'Email', hint: 'Enter Your Email', required: true },
        { type: "password" },
        { type: "email" }
      ]}
    />
  </AmplifyAuthenticator>
);
}
```

From the documentation [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/react#custom-form-fields)

> If you’d like to customize the form fields in the Authenticator Sign In or Sign Up component, you can do so by using the formFields property.

For more details on this customization see the `amplify-form-field` [prop documentation](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/main/packages/amplify-ui-components/src/components/amplify-form-field#properties) and the internal [`FormFieldType` interface](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/main/packages/amplify-ui-components/src/components/amplify-auth-fields/amplify-auth-fields-interface.ts#L3).

For example:

```
...
<AmplifyAuthenticator usernameAlias="email">
  <AmplifySignUp
    slot="sign-up"
    usernameAlias="email"
    formFields={[
      {
        type: "email",
        label: "Custom Email Label",
        placeholder: "Custom email placeholder"
        inputProps: { required: true, autocomplete: "username" },
      },
      {
        type: "password",
        label: "Custom Password Label",
        placeholder: "Custom password placeholder",
        inputProps: { required: true, autocomplete: "new-password" },
      },
      {
        type: "phone_number",
        label: "Custom Phone Label",
        placeholder: "Custom phone placeholder",
      },
    ]} 
  />
  <AmplifySignIn slot="sign-in" usernameAlias="email" />
</AmplifyAuthenticator>
...
```

Yields:

[image]

I hope this helps, I'm still trying to figure out the custom cognito attribute stuff in a sign-up form, which I'm sure is similar to the custom `signUp` calls such as:

```
await Auth.signUp({
  username: 'someuser', password: 'mycoolpassword',
  attributes: {
    email: 'someuser@somedomain.com', 'custom:favorite_ice_cream': 'chocolate'
  }
})
```

**Examples**

JS:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import { AmplifyAuthenticator, AmplifySignOut } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import { AuthState, onAuthUIStateChange } from '@aws-amplify/ui-components';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

const AuthStateApp = () => {
    const [authState, setAuthState] = React.useState();
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        return onAuthUIStateChange((nextAuthState, authData) => {
            setAuthState(nextAuthState);
            setUser(authData)
        });
    }, []);

  return authState === AuthState.SignedIn && user ? (
      <div className="App">
          <div>Hello, {user.username}</div>
          <AmplifySignOut />
      </div>
    ) : (
      <AmplifyAuthenticator />
  );
}

export default AuthStateApp;
```

TS:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import { AmplifyAuthenticator, AmplifySignOut } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import { AuthState, onAuthUIStateChange } from '@aws-amplify/ui-components';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

const AuthStateApp: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    const [authState, setAuthState] = React.useState<AuthState>();
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState<object | undefined>();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        return onAuthUIStateChange((nextAuthState, authData) => {
            setAuthState(nextAuthState);
            setUser(authData)
        });
    }, []);

  return authState === AuthState.SignedIn && user ? (
      <div className="App">
          <div>Hello, {user.username}</div>
          <AmplifySignOut />
      </div>
  ) : (
      <AmplifyAuthenticator />
  );
}

export default AuthStateApp;
```

Comment: @lucas-andrade did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is still wondering if this is possible, the new version of Amplify UI now supports a Select Field component that can be tailored into your Authenticator.

```js
import { SelectField } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

export const DefaultSelectFieldExample = () => (
  <SelectField label="Fruit">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  </SelectField>
);
```

For more, refer to documentation here https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/components/selectfield